# How to update an entire Dataset Row?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to update a row (having index `numberInt`) values of a given dataset `dFIdx` using values of another row from another dataset `dFInitIdx` (the row of the second dataset having different index `j`). I try in `JAVA` like the following :

```
for (String colName : dFInitIdx.columns())
    dFIdx =  dFIdx.where(col("id").equalTo(numberInt)).withColumn(colName,dFInitIdx.where(col("id").equalTo(j)).col(colName));
```

But i am getting this error :

> Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: id. Please
> check if the right attribute(s) are used

How to achieve that update of one row in `JAVA` (preferably a one liner) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both of your Datasets seem to have the same columns, you can use a `join()` method to merge them together based on your `numberInt` and `j` conditions, in order to `select()` (at least) the `id` column value of the first Dataset `dFIdx` and all the other columns from the second Dataset `dFInitIdx`.

`dFIdx` data sample:

```
+---+--------+---------+
| id|hundreds|thousands|
+---+--------+---------+
|  1|     100|     1000|
|  2|     200|     2000|
|  3|     300|     3000|
+---+--------+---------+
```

`dFInitIdx` data sample:

```
+---+--------+---------+
| id|hundreds|thousands|
+---+--------+---------+
|  1|     101|     1001|
|  2|     201|     2001|
|  3|     301|     3001|
+---+--------+---------+
```

Let's say that for the given data samples `numberInt` and `j` are (hardcoded) set as:

1. `numberInt == 1`
2. `j == 2`

The solution will look like this:

```
dFIdx.join(dFInitIdx, dFIdx("id").equalTo(numberInt) && dFInitIdx("id").equalTo(j))
          .select(dFIdx("id"), dFInitIdx("hundreds"), dFInitIdx("thousands"))
```

And we can see the result of the query with `show()` as seen below:

```
+---+--------+---------+
| id|hundreds|thousands|
+---+--------+---------+
|  1|     201|     2001|
+---+--------+---------+
```

Comment: The main reason that `join` was used here is because resorting to `for`-like loops or UDFs instead of native Spark SQL methods is usually the death of optimisation. This is a good rule of thumb in general, to always try and use Spark SQL native methods instead of typical Java/Scala/Python commands (9 times out of 10 you can always solve something just with methods like join, select, where, etc.). After all, by using Spark's own API it's of course gonna be easier for it to actually _understand_ what you are trying to do and optimise everything for you under the hood.

Comment: Alright thanks, and what about methods like `dFIdx.foreach(row ->...` or else `map()` in this case ?

Comment: They are indeed specified in Spark's libraries, so they can be used/preferred in similar scenarios. Of course you can experiment with different solutions using Spark methods to pick the most efficient one (it is usually the most simple one, but not all the time).